# Calculate duration of non-continuous overlapping time intervals

Tags: vba, excel, time

I am trying to calculate the total duration of overlap between multiple events. Each event can overlap with multiple other events in any arrangement. I need to calculate the total amount of time any single event overlaps with any other event. The data I have looks like this.

```
event  timeStart   timeEnd
1       15:00       22:00
2       12:00       18:00
3       20:00       23:00
4       16:00       17:00
5       10:00       14:00

Output:

event  timeOverlap
1       05:00       '03:00 (1,2) + 02:00 (1,3)
2       04:00       '03:00 (1,2) + 01:00 (2,4)
3       02:00       '02:00 (1,3)
4       01:00       '01:00 (2,4)
5       02:00       '02:00 (2,5)
```

I'm trying to do this in Excel VBA. My main problem right now is finding a way to sum up discontinuous overlaps, e.g. event 1 or event 2. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: To clarify, I would like to avoid double counting, which is why I didn't include the overlap between (1,4) in the calculation for event 1. The output should show the sum of the overlaps that would result in the largest overlap duration.

Here's part of the code I'm using. Right now it calculates the longest continuous overlap between multiple events. It doesn't sum up discontinuous overlaps.

```
'DECLARE VARIABLES
Dim timeStart() As Date   'start times of cases
Dim timeEnd() As Date     'end times of cases
Dim ovlpStart() As Double   'start times of overlap regions for cases
Dim ovlpEnd() As Double     'end times of overlap regions for cases
Dim totalRows As Long       'total number of cases`

'RETRIEVE NUMBER OF ROWS
totalRows = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(1))

'STORE COLUMN DATA FROM EXCEL SHEET INTO ARRAYS
ReDim timeStart(1 To totalRows)
ReDim timeEnd(1 To totalRows)
ReDim ovlpStart(1 To totalRows)
ReDim ovlpEnd(1 To totalRows)

'FILL IN ARRAYS WITH DATA FROM SPREADSHEET
For i = 2 To totalRows
    timeStart(i) = Cells(i, 3).Value
    timeEnd(i) = Cells(i, 4).Value

    'Initialize ovlpStart and ovlpEnd
    ovlpStart(i) = 1
    ovlpEnd(i) = 0
Next

'FILL IN CONCURRENCE COLUMN WITH ALL ZEROS TO START
For i = 2 To totalRows
    Cells(i, 6).Value = "0"
Next

'SEARCH FOR CONCURRENT TIME INTERVALS
For i = 2 To totalRows
    For j = (i + 1) To totalRows

            'Check if the times overlap b/w cases i and j
            Dim diff1 As Double
            Dim diff2 As Double
            diff1 = timeEnd(j) - timeStart(i)
            diff2 = timeEnd(i) - timeStart(j)
            If diff1 > 0 And diff2 > 0 Then

                'Mark cases i and j as concurrent in spreadsheet
                Cells(i, 6).Value = "1"
                Cells(j, 6).Value = "1"

                'Determine overlap start and end b/w cases i and j, store as x and y
                Dim x As Double
                Dim y As Double
                If timeStart(i) > timeStart(j) Then
                    x = timeStart(i)
                Else
                    x = timeStart(j)
                End If
                If timeEnd(i) < timeEnd(j) Then
                    y = timeEnd(i)
                Else
                    y = timeEnd(j)
                End If

                    'Update ovlpStart and ovlpEnd values for cases i and j if overlap region has increased for either
                    If x < ovlpStart(i) Then
                        ovlpStart(i) = x
                    End If
                    If x < ovlpStart(j) Then
                        ovlpStart(j) = x
                    End If
                    If y > ovlpEnd(i) Then
                        ovlpEnd(i) = y
                    End If
                    If y > ovlpEnd(j) Then
                        ovlpEnd(j) = y
                    End If
                End If

    Next
Next

'DETERMINE DURATION OF OVERLAP, PRINT ONTO SPREADSHEET
Dim ovlpDuration As Double
For i = 2 To totalRows
    ovlpDuration = ovlpEnd(i) - ovlpStart(i)
    If Not ovlpDuration Then
        Cells(i, 7).Value = ovlpDuration
    Else
        Cells(i, 7).Value = 0
    End If
Next`
```

Comment: In your logic, why is there no overlap between (1,4)?

Comment: You should post an example of your code to sum the overlaps.

Comment: Are you OK with "double counting" your overlaps? e.g. In your logic, you show event 2 counting 1 hour for the overlap (2,4), and you show event 4 counting 1 hour for the overlap (2,4). If this is not OK, how would you decide which event gets to count it?

Comment: Are you planning to fix the data in this question? If not, are you planning to address the concerns mentioned in these comments and answer response as to the validity of your logic?

Comment: I still do not understand why event 2 is 4 hours. (2, 1) is correct at 3 hours but (2, 4) is already covered by (2, 1). What is missing is (2, 5) which is 2 hours outside of everything else. The correct answer appears to me to be 5, not 4.

Comment: You are right, that is a mistake on my part. Event 2 should output 5 hours as you described. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Excel Application object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194565.aspx) has the [Intersect method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195772.aspx) available. If you treat the hours as imaginary rows on an imaginary worksheet and calculate the rows.count of a possible intersection between them, you can use that integer as the hours interval in a [TimeSerial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ws25fd2z.aspx) function.

**Loose Overlap with Intersect**

```
Sub overlapHours()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, ohrs As Double
    With Worksheets("Sheet7")
        For i = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
            ohrs = 0
            For j = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
                If j <> i And Not Intersect(Range(Hour(.Cells(i, "B").Value2) & ":" & Hour(.Cells(i, "C").Value2)), _
                                            Range(Hour(.Cells(j, "B").Value2) & ":" & Hour(.Cells(j, "C").Value2))) Is Nothing Then
                    ohrs = ohrs + TimeSerial(Intersect(Range(Hour(.Cells(i, "B").Value2) & ":" & Hour(.Cells(i, "C").Value2)), _
                                                       Range(Hour(.Cells(j, "B").Value2) & ":" & Hour(.Cells(j, "C").Value2))).Rows.Count - 1, 0, 0)
                End If
            Next j
            .Cells(i, 4).NumberFormat = "[hh]:mm"
            .Cells(i, 4) = ohrs
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

To avoid repeating the overlap times from one time period to the next, build a [Union](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834621.aspx) of the intersects of the imaginary rows. Unions can be discontiguous ranges so we need to cycle through the [Range.Areas property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196243.aspx) to achieve a correct count of the [Range.Rows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195745.aspx) property.

**Strict Overlap with Intersect and Union**

```
Sub intersectHours()
    Dim a As Long, i As Long, j As Long, rng As Range, ohrs As Double
    With Worksheets("Sheet7")
        For i = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
            ohrs = 0: Set rng = Nothing
            For j = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
                If j <> i And Not Intersect(.Range(Hour(.Cells(i, "B").Value2) & ":" & Hour(.Cells(i, "C").Value2) - 1), _
                                            .Range(Hour(.Cells(j, "B").Value2) & ":" & Hour(.Cells(j, "C").Value2) - 1)) Is Nothing Then
                    If rng Is Nothing Then
                        Set rng = Intersect(.Range(Hour(.Cells(i, "B").Value2) & ":" & Hour(.Cells(i, "C").Value2) - 1), _
                                            .Range(Hour(.Cells(j, "B").Value2) & ":" & Hour(.Cells(j, "C").Value2) - 1))
                    Else
                        Set rng = Union(rng, Intersect(.Range(Hour(.Cells(i, "B").Value2) & ":" & Hour(.Cells(i, "C").Value2) - 1), _
                                                       .Range(Hour(.Cells(j, "B").Value2) & ":" & Hour(.Cells(j, "C").Value2) - 1)))
                    End If
                End If
            Next j
            If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                For a = 1 To rng.Areas.Count
                    ohrs = ohrs + TimeSerial(rng.Areas(a).Rows.Count, 0, 0)
                Next a
            End If
            .Cells(i, 6).NumberFormat = "[hh]:mm"
            .Cells(i, 6) = ohrs
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

[image: time_overlap_intersect_proof]

My results differ from the ones you posted for event 2 but I have traced my logic backwards and forwards and cannot see an error.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I entirely follow your logic. For example, I don't see why 1 & 4 don't overlap.

However, it's looking as though you'd just take the later of the compared start times and the earlier of the compared end times and subtract the latter from the former. If the result is positive then there's an overlap so aggregate the result within a loop.

I'm assuming your time values are in the `Time` format (ie hh:mm) and therefore `Doubles`.

The code below hardcodes your ranges so you'll need to adjust that as suits, but at least you could see the logic to get you going:

```
Dim tStart As Double
Dim tEnd As Double
Dim tDiff As Double
Dim v As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim output(1 To 5, 1 To 2) As Variant

v = Sheet1.Range("A2:C6").Value2
For i = 1 To 5
    For j = i + 1 To 5
        tStart = IIf(v(i, 2) > v(j, 2), v(i, 2), v(j, 2))
        tEnd = IIf(v(i, 3) < v(j, 3), v(i, 3), v(j, 3))
        tDiff = tEnd - tStart
        If tDiff > 0 Then
            output(i, 1) = output(i, 1) + tDiff
            output(j, 1) = output(j, 1) + tDiff
            output(i, 2) = output(i, 2) & i & "&" & j & " "
            output(j, 2) = output(j, 2) & i & "&" & j & " "
        End If
    Next
Next

Sheet1.Range("B9:C13").Value = output
```

Comment: fwiw, the logic in the sample data **does** appear flawed, rushed and/or just plain lazy.

Comment: Apologies, I should have clarified. I'm trying to avoid double-counting. For event 1, I'm trying to calculate the longest overlap duration. The overlap between (1,2) already "includes" the overlap between (1,4) and I don't want to double-count. The final calculation should be the sum of the overlaps that would result in the largest total overlap time. Sorry, I'm new at this and hope my language makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will try it when I get home from work.